# Calculating Standard Deviation - NaN Error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the standard deviation yet I keep getting a NaN error, it's been a while but I can't seem to spot where the error is coming from, any helps appreciated. The values in the array are accelerometer values e.g. -1.416170358657837

```
function classifyMotion() {

/* array to hold last 300 samples */
var lastBatchOfSamples = [];

if (devArray > 1200) {

    /* Clear if more than 60s worth of data */
    devArray.length = 0;
}

/* retrieve last 300 samples and store in own array*/
lastBatchOfSamples = devArray.slice(Math.max(devArray.length - 300));

function standardDeviation(values) {

    var avg = average(values);

    var squareDiffs = lastBatchOfSamples.map(function(value) {
        var diff = value - avg;
        var sqrDiff = diff * diff;
        return sqrDiff;
    });

    var avgSquareDiff = average(squareDiffs);

    var stdDev = Math.sqrt(avgSquareDiff);
    return stdDev;
}

function average(lastBatchOfSamples) {
    var sum = lastBatchOfSamples.reduce(function(sum, value) {
        return sum + value;
    }, 0);
    test2 = sum;

    var avg = sum / lastBatchOfSamples.length;
    return avg;
}
var deviation = standardDeviation(lastBatchOfSamples);

}
```

Comment: Every time you call `average` you pass in a value, but `average` doesn't take any parameters as it's defined

Comment: Woops, sorry. I'm after editing the example again. Incidentally, I hard coded the array to 1,2,3,4,5 as a test which returns the answer. Could it possibly the type of data in the array ?

Comment: Which array did you hard code? You're passing in `value` to average but not using it anywhere. You're also taking `Math.max` of 1 term which will always return the term.

Comment: you never use the `value` argument that is passed to `average`. the `value` in `(function(sum, value)` is a named argument in a function expression, and is completely unrelated to the `value` passed in the `average` function. also, that function is clearly doing something more than taking an average of `value`?

Comment: @chiliNUT, nope average simply calculates the average. I passed the `lastBatchOfSamples` into the `average` function which seems to be more or less the same when I pass the same values through Excel. One thing I did notice is that when the accelerometer is still, it obviously generates negative numbers, which when averaged will of course also give a negative and was returning NaN

Comment: but the code looked like your intent was to average the squarediffs

Comment: which should never be negative. so, I think your code looks ok, though it is confusing that the named argument to your average function is `lastBatchOfSamples`. anyway, is it working now?

Comment: From what I can tell its working now, yes. I called it at `lastBatchOfSamples`as it's accelerometer data and I'm only using the last 15 seconds of data or so each time. Although I do agree it needs a better name.